# How to determine enemy ammo levels

Tags: overwatch

When playing as D.Va, a technique I often find myself using, is to [boost into an opponent followed by a short burst of fire](https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/3t1w5n/how_to_be_a_beast_at_dva/?ref=share&ref_source=link) from my fusion cannons, then I pull up my defence matrix as they almost always return fire if they aren't dead and haven't tried to run away. After they've fired a few shots I drop my defence matrix and return fire.

I feel that during a reload would be an ideal time at which to attack up close in order to finish them off.

How can I tell whether they are out of ammo or about to need to reload?

Comment: I know what you're thinking. 'Did he fire six shots or only five'? Well to tell you the truth, in all this excitement, i kind of lost track myself. But being that this is a .44 Magnum, the most powerful handgun in the world, and would blow your head clean off, you've got to ask yourself one question: 'Do I feel lucky?' Well do ya, punk?

Answer (score 7):

There is no way apart from counting bullets (for slow firing heroes like Repaer on Phara ) and "feeling" how much time they've shot for, and how much time they have left to shoot, for fast shooting heroes like Tracer.

It's easy enough to count Phara or Repaer's or Anna's bullets once you memorize how much bullets they carry. I'd suggest you going in the practice range with each of the heroes you'll have to learn the feel time and just start shooting getting the hang of how much time they can shoot before they'd have to reload, soon enough you'd know for how long you can press Mouse1 before reloading.

By the way I use the feel method when fighting exactly D.va. (I only go against her 1on1 as soldier, so I'd shoot you, as soon as you have your shields up I'd stop shooting and basically force you to keep the shield up and me still having plenty bullets. As soon as I feel you're out of shield I'd melt D.va's head with 1 mag.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with this is you're assuming that they're going to be showing up in the same area you are with a full mag. If they show up with say, three rounds left and you're trying to count down from full, it's going to throw your timing off. Depending on which champion you're going up against, your best bet will be to let your tanks draw fire, and when you notice the pause, try to take them out from a point of advantage.

Do note though, some people are going to be clever and intentionally pause to make you think they're reloading and bait you into a trap. In a game like Overwatch there's a lot of pressure to keep dog piling and keeping the progressing the objectives, or keeping them away, so a lot of split-second rash decisions are made.

Answer (score -1):

You can "know" how much ammo they have for only two heroes. The first one is Sombra. On her gun there is a hexadecimal ammo counter, and yeah, I know this is nearly impossible to see, but it is there). The second hero is Orisa. As she uses ammo on her `fusion driver`, the pitch of the firing sound will change.